# replace a numerical column by a character column in R with a defined mapping

Tags: r, mapping, dplyr, tidyr

I did some searching but could not find an answer to my problem.

Say I have a data frame with a column `student_id` in integers and some other columns. I also have another mapping table containing two columns, with the 1st one being `student_id` and the 2nd one `student_name` in strings. What is the best way of replacing the `student_id` column with `student_name`? Note that the mapping table is unique, but the data frame can have multiple student ids that are the same.

If it helps, I'm working with `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say `grades` is your data.frame with records for every grade awarded from every class offered by a school with fields (grade, student id, class number) for the last 10 years, and `roster` is a list with one record per student with all the names and ids of students that attended the school in the same time period.

Roster has one record per student, and grades has multiple records per student.

You can push student names from roster with dplyr by calling

```
library(dplyr)
gradesWithStudentNames <- 
        grades %>% 
        left_join(select(roster,studentID,studentName),
                  by=`studentID')
```

A left join will include every row of the table `grades` even if there isn't a matching student in `roster` (student name will be missing in that case).  using `inner_join` will omit such records, and `outer_join` will include records of students in `roster` who did not attend any classes (with missing values for the class number and grade).

I would recommend reading the vignette titled 'Two-table Verbs' which describes the various joins and can be found using `browseVignettes('dplyr')`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does partly solve my problem in that I can add the `studentName` column to my data frame. However, I still want to 'replace' the `studentID` column by the `studentName` colume and also would like to keep the position of the column. I was able to achieve this by: 

`grades <- grades[, c(c('grade', 'studentName'), setdiff(names(grades), c('grade', 'studentID', 'studentName')))]`  

The data frame I have has many more columns than this example. So that's why I used the setdiff function.